# Aptana Studio 3 AND Titanium Studio on OS X (Snow Leopard)

Tags: php, macos, titanium, aptana

Is it ok to run BOTH of these on my mac (not at the same moment, of course)  Will I run into conflicts if I run both on the same machine?  Most of my work is web development in php so I don't want to break my nicely working Studio 3 installation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could run both on the same machine, as Titanium Studio includes all the features and plugins and Aptana Studio 3.  Titanium Studio will prompt for a different default workspace location at the startup (user.home/Documents/Titanium Studio Workspace), but you could change it to use the same workspace as Aptana Studio 3 (default to user.home/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace).